# How to resolve error 'Could not find or load main class Files\KeyCloak\keycloak-22.0.1\bin\..' on Win10?

Tags: windows, keycloak

When trying to run bin/kc.bat on Windows 10, the following error appears: Could not find or load main class Files\KeyCloak\keycloak-22.0.1\bin\

PATH-variable is set properly: [PATH:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unmbO.png) 
[Mistake description:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjsF9.jpg)

The error is not being googled properly.
Checked the integrity of the archive + correctness of PAT-var.